# Error -> name 'result' is not defined - time series project in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, time-series, p-value

I am writing a code to get the p-value in Python.

```
def adfuller_test(GDP):
    result=adfuller(GDP)
    labels = ['ADF Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations']
    for value,label in zip(result,labels):
        print(label+' : '+str(value) )
        
if result[1] <= 0.05:
    print("strong evidence against the null hypothesis(Ho), reject the null hypothesis. Data is stationary")
else:
    print("weak evidence against null hypothesis,indicating it is non-stationary ")

adfuller_test(data['GDP'])
```

While executing the above code, I am getting the error (mentioned below).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9032\1780834004.py in <module>
      6         print(label+' : '+str(value) )
      7 
----> 8 if result[1] <= 0.05:
      9     print("strong evidence against the null hypothesis(Ho), reject the null hypothesis. Data is stationary")
     10 else:

NameError: name 'result' is not defined
```

Please let me know how to fix the error, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pasted the code here incorrectly, you clearly have an indentation problem. Needs to be written like this:

```
def adfuller_test(GDP):
    result=adfuller(GDP)
    labels = ['ADF Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations']
    for value,label in zip(result,labels):
        print(label+' : '+str(value) )
    if result[1] <= 0.05:
        print("strong evidence against the null hypothesis(Ho), reject the null hypothesis. Data is stationary")
    else:
        print("weak evidence against null hypothesis,indicating it is non-stationary ")

adfuller_test(data['GDP'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is referring to `result` as if it's global, but it's defined in the function. In order to access the variable outside of the function as if it was global, you can define it like this:

```py
def adfuller_test(GDP):
    global result
    result=adfuller(GDP)
    labels = ['ADF Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations']
    for value,label in zip(result,labels):
        print(label+' : '+str(value) )
```

For more context, have a look at the section "The global Keyword
" of [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) as well as [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_variables_global3).

Comment: Or, far better than messing with global variables... return result if you want to use it outside of the function...